# how to extend typescript interfaces?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So i have interface for the request that has header from `IoperationParam` and body would be same as `patientList` that is array of object but it throws error patientId can not assigsigned to `IGetSpecialtyQuestionsParam` any idea what needs to be corrected here ?

main.interface.ts

```
    export interface IGetSpecialtyQuestionsParam extends IOperationParam {
        patientList: (ISpecialtyQuestionsEntity)[];
    }
    export interface ISpecialtyQuestionsEntity {
        /**
         * <H3>This maps to ESL patientId<H3>
         */
        patientId: string;
        /**
         * 1982-01-10
         */
        dateOfBirth: string;
        /**
         * Female
         */
        gender: "Male"|"Female";
        /**
         * We can default this;
         * Specialty HBS
         */

        sourceSystem: string;


        rxInfo?: (RxInfoEntity)[] | null;
    }

export interface IOperationParam {
    appName: string;
    appId: string
}
```

Comment: What is `IOperationParam`? What is the full error message?

Comment: Should it be patientList: <ISpecialtyQuestionsEntity>[];

Comment: @SLaks `IOperationsParam` are standard header for the request, no issue with that problem is with patientList so request would be `{ header: {}, patientlist:[{}]`

Comment: 1. What is exact error message? 2. What `IOperationParam` looks like?

Comment: when request comes in it fails specialtyId is required that is part of patientList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing classes and interfaces. Interfaces only define the *shape* of the data, not default values.

Your interfaces should be:

```
export interface IOperationParam {
  appName: string;
  appId: string
}

export interface IGetSpecialtyQuestionsParam extends IOperationParam {
  patientList: ISpecialtyQuestionsEntity[];
}

export interface ISpecialtyQuestionsEntity {
  patientId: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
  gender: string;
  sourceSystem: string;
  rxInfo?: RxInfoEntity[];
}
```

The error you stated: "...patientId can not assigsigned to IGetSpecialtyQuestionsParam..."

is happening because `IGetSpecialtyQuestionsParam` extends `IOperationParam` which doesn't have the property: `patientId`.

So, you need to either have `patientId` in the `IOperationParam` interface, or add it as part of the `IGetSpecialtyQuestionsParam` interface, or extend a common interface... whatever works best for your app.